# How to write a script for searching only first line and last line in a text in and remove a "-" from there?

Tags: vbscript

I have over 5k text files in  some folders. Now I need to only remove `"-"` from the first line and last line in each text file.

I dont know how to do it, is there anyone who can help? what should i use to do this? vbs or normal batch

OS: Windows7

text file like this:  01.txt

---

```
% 01-A247M15 G70 

N0001 G30 G17 X-100 Y-100 Z0

N0002 G31 G90 X100 Y100 Z45

N0003 ; --PART NO.:  NC-HON.PHX01.COVER-SHOE.DET-1000.050

N0004 ; --TOOL:  8.55 X .3937 

N0005 D00 Q50 P01 +8.5500 ; TOOL DIA 

N0006 D00 Q51 P01 +0.3920 ; TOOL RAD 

N0007  % 01-A247M15 G70
```

---

Please help.

Comment: are the lines included in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VBScript it's simpler...

First you parse the text file into an array: http://www.windowsitpro.com/content/content/46489/Listing_01.txt

```
Function FileToArray(ByVal strFile, ByVal blnUNICODE)
  Const FOR_READING = 1
  Dim objFSO, objTS, strContents

' BEGIN CALLOUT A
  FileToArray = Split("")
' END CALLOUT A

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, FOR_READING, False, blnUNICODE)
    If Err = 0 Then
      strContents = objTS.ReadAll
      objTS.Close
' BEGIN CALLOUT B
      FileToArray = Split(strContents, vbNewLine)
' END CALLOUT B
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Then you do a REPLACE on the first and last row of the array and write it to another file, or the same file.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have not indicated which script you want perl, unix.  So I will give you algorithm,

```
1.  read first line
2.  Split with - as delimiter (cut in unix)
3.  paste the split words in redirect to new file >> newfile
4.  get count of lines of file (wc in unix)
5.  get the 2nd line till last one but line and append to new file (head and tail in unix)
6.  do the same steps 1, 2, and 3 for last line and append to new file
```

Comment: From the question "what should i use to do this? vbs or normal batch". VBS == VBScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one liners if you have access to Linux/ Linux like environment (MinGW, Cygwin etc)

```
    find ./ -name *.txt | xargs sed -i '1s/-//g'
    find ./ -name *.txt | xargs sed -i '$s/-//g'
```

Edited to include substitution in last line :)